# How can I nest Icon component in Input component in Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to display compass icon at the right side of inside input;
[Here's is my current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsZXk.png)

```
import { CompassTwoTone } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Input } from 'antd';
const IconInInput = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Input placeholder="Basic usage" />
            <CompassTwoTone/>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Input` does have a `suffix` prop. ([doc here](https://ant.design/components/input/#components-input-demo-presuffix)) :

```html
import { CompassTwoTone } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Input } from 'antd';
const IconInInput = () => {
  return (
      <>
          <Input placeholder="Basic usage" suffix={<CompassTwoTone/>}/>
      </>
  );
}
```